# Let $T: C^{1} \rightarrow C^{0}$ be the operator such that $T(f)(x) = f^{1}(x) $, is this operator uniformly continuous?

Tags: analysis

$C^{1}$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions and $C^{0}$ the space of continuous functions, both defined on the real interval $[0,1]$. Both spaces equipped with $d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]|f(x) - g(x)|}$ as metric.
$f^{1}(x)$ is the first derivative of f.

Now, is this operator uniformly continuous? It seems so but going about this demonstration became too confusing for me. Could you guys give me any hints, please?

Comment: Look at the zero function and a function with graph being zero everywhere except for a little, but very narrow, peak.

Comment: Are you sure it's continuous? Since it's linear, there is a fairly easy way to check continuity...

Comment: Indeed, @ryan221b,  I saw some examples like $f_{n} = sin(nx)$ which totally contradict my intuition about continuity. I'd like to develop a demonstration without using this.

Comment: What are the norms on the two spaces? If $C^1$ is considered as a subspace of $C^0$ with the induced norm, see the above comments. However, if $C^1$ has the norm $||f|| = \sup_{[0,1]}|f(x)| + \sup_{[0,1]}|f'(x)|$, then it is simple to show that $T$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @JaneDoé, that's the sup metric indeed, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: OK, then existence of functions that are "close to 0" but with a "large derivative at some point" would show that $T$ is not continuous, wouldn't it? Do such functions exist?

Comment: I found this example of a sequence $f_{n} = \sin(nx)$ which would fall in that category.  I'll try and write a formal proof without using it as counterexample. Any hints in that direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuity of the linear map

$f \mapsto f': C^1[0, 1] \to C[0, 1] \tag 1$

depends on the norms placed on $C^1[0, 1]$ and $C[0, 1]$.  If, as is typical, we define

$\Vert \cdot \Vert _1:  C^1[0, 1] \to \Bbb R \tag 2$

*via*

$\Vert f \Vert_1 = \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f(x) \vert + \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f'(x) \vert, \tag 3$

and

$\Vert \cdot \Vert_0:  C[0, 1] \to \Bbb R \tag 4$

by

$\Vert f \Vert_0 = \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f(x) \vert, \tag 5$

then the mapping (1) is in fact continuous, since it is a bounded linear map:

$\Vert f' \Vert_0 = \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f'(x) \vert \le \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0w, 1]} \vert f(x) \vert + \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f'(x) \vert = \Vert f \Vert_1. \tag 6$

However, if we use the metric

$d(f, g) = \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert \tag 7$

which is in fact the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_0$ norm,

$d(f, g) = \Vert f - g \Vert_0, \tag 8$

on both $C[0, 1]$ and $C^1[0, 1]$, then $f \to f'$ is *not* continuous, since a function may be $\Vert \cdot \Vert$-small yet have an arbitrarily large derivative, for example

$f_k(x) = a\sin (kx) \tag 9$

is bounded in absolute value by $\vert a \vert$, but

$\vert f_k'(x) \vert = \vert ak\cos(kx) \vert \tag{10}$

becomes arbitrarily large as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: @upStoneLock:  my pleasure, my friend, and thanks for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 0):

This function is not continuous. For you can take any function on the real line and rescale the parameter ($f(x) \mapsto f(rx)$ for large $r$) to make the derivative large without affecting the $C^0$ norm of the function.

For a specific example, consider $f_n(x) = n^{-1} \sin (n^2x)$. As $n$ gets large, $f_n(x)$ goes to $0$ in $C^1(0)$ with the uniform norm, but $\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x) = n \cos(n^2x)$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bit long for a comment, so I post as an answer.

In reply to your intuition about continuity, linearity “simplifies” continuity in that you only have to check continuity at 0 to determine continuity on the whole (vector) space. This is because

$$\|T(f) - T(g)\| = \|T(f-g)\| = \|T(h)\|$$

since we can replace $f-g$ by any other vector $h$.

From that it's easy to check that continuity is equivalent to *boundedness*: there is a constant $M > 0$ such that

$$ \|T(f)\| \leq M\| f \|$$

for all $f$.

So to show that a (linear) operator between normed spaces is continuous, all you have to do is estimated a suitable $M$. On the other hand, to show discontinuity it is enough to pick a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ that violate the inequality, say

$$ \| T(f_n) \| \geq n \| f_n \| $$

(You need infinitely many: if you only had a finite number, then you could pick the biggest norm and you'd be bounded again.)

In general, derivative operators are not bounded on $C^1([0,1])$: just think of polynomials $(x^n)_n$.